# Sync IMAP emails from second PC

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I lost some emails at work but I think I have these emails on my laptop. I use Outlook for work and on my laptop.

How would I upload the missing emails or sync emails from Outlook on my laptop with the server? I thought it would be automatic but it's not happening.

Comment: Are you actually using IMAP?

Comment: Yes. I've just had to accept the emails are lost and had to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you configure your account as an IMAP account on both computers?

> I lost some emails at work but I think I have these emails on my laptop

As I know, if you configure your account as an IMAP account, emails can be synchronized on multiple devices. Please log in to your web mail to check whether the lost emails exist.

If the emails do exist on the web version, please try to send/receive mail manually and check if lost emails can be synchronized.

If it does't work, considering the damage of data file or profile, it is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(control panel>mail>show profile>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Comment: Yes, both accounts are IMAP and web mail doe snot have the missing emails.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I know, if the messages are not displayed on the web mail, it means that those messages may not be synchronized to your server, so they cannot be synchronized on the second PC. Please check whether these emails really exist on your laptop. If so, it’s suggested that you could try to send/receive mail manually and wait a moment until you can view the lost emails in web mail.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.